# Where can I find spell schools for Wizard spells?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

In Pillars of Eternity II, there are now [subclasses](https://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Subclasses) (kits) for each class. E.g., Wizards can be Evokers, Enchanters, etc. These make the character more proficient with that school, but prevent them from casting from 2 other schools.

However, I've tried searching for which spells fall under which school, and I haven't found it. Neither the Official Wiki nor Fextralife have it. Which spells fall under which school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schools can be found here:

https://pillarsofeternity2.wiki.fextralife.com/Wizard+Abilities

and here:

[image]

Comment: while links are helpful, they are subject to link rot. it is best to copy the relevant info from the link so that the information therein can be preserved if the link dies.

Comment: Sadly, the info would have to be copied from each individual spell: if you clicked on the link, you'd see that the info is not available in aggregate. This is still better than the official wiki, which doesn't have the info in any capacity.

That's the best info I've found so far, and I've searched quite a lot (I even went as far as trying to configure a web crawler to scrape the info from the site into a table--beyond my skills). If that's not a good answer, I'm happy to remove it.